# Delaying flip event from firing at the same time with setInterval

Tags: jquery

Right now this works, I'm just trying to make it so the '`flip`' effect isn't at the exact same time for all 4 elements.  Is there a way to delay it by a little bit, or the best result would be to do it right after the previous one finishes flipping?

`flip()` is a jquery plugin that flips an object 180 degrees and reveals the "back side" of it.

Here is the timing code I am using to automate the flip every 30 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#activitiesCard, #callStatsCard, #agentsContactedCard, #agentsSalesCard").flip({
            trigger: 'manual'
        });


        $("#activitiesCard, #callStatsCard, #agentsContactedCard, #agentsSalesCard").each(function (i) {
            var el = $(this);
            setInterval(function () {
                el.flip('toggle');
            }, 30000);
        });

    });

</script>
```

This works, but each "card" is flipped at the exact same time.

JQuery Flip: https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Comment: Can you please add a link to the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the flip happens at a constant speed (by default, 500ms), so that makes the calculations simple: for the `i-th` element, you can just start the timer at `30 sec + 500 * i`. The trick is to wrap the `setInterval()` in a `setTimeout()` so each element gets its own fixed delay before starting its thirty second interval countdown.

```
$(selector).each(function (i) {
  var el = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      el.flip('toggle');
    }, 30000);
  }, 500 * i);
});
```

Comment: That was genius!  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index value provided by jQuery.each() as multiplier for the timeout function. Of course, feel free to play with the arithmetic to your liking. Example:

```
$("#activitiesCard, #callStatsCard, #agentsContactedCard, #agentsSalesCard").each(function (index, value) {
        var el = $(this);
        setInterval(function () {
            el.flip('toggle');
        }, 30000 + (index * 2000);
    });
```

Comment: This works the very first time, but it looks like he index value keeps being added to.  So the second time, it takes slightly longer, the third time it takes even longer.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Store the elements in an array, create a function that pops each element off the array and flips it with a timer, then recursively call that function in the timer function until the array is empty.

```js
var elements=[];

function flipElementIfAny() {
  if(elements.length > 0) {
    el = elements.shift();
    setTimeout( function() {
      $(el).css('background', '#aa0'); // simulate flip
      flipElementIfAny();
      }, 600);
  }
}

function flipElements() {
  elements=$('div').toArray();
  flipElementIfAny();
}

flipElements();
```

```css
  div {
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #a0a;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
```